# Get values from form inputs after submit

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activeadmin

I update my Article Model in ActiveAdmin page that has form with inputs :title, :body, :pages. Are there any ways to get values from those inputs in admin/Article.rb after pushing Update?

In admin/Article.rb

```
form do |f|
 inputs "Article Info" do
  input :title
  input :body
  input :pages
 end
  actions
end
```

For example i gonna use method:

```
def get_values_from_form
 {title: ..., body: ..., pages: ...}
end
```

Comment: Assuming all is set up correctly, those values should be available in your params.

Comment: Read the documentation on [resource customization](https://activeadmin.info/2-resource-customization.html) and [Inherited Resources](https://github.com/activeadmin/inherited_resources) to understand what to do here.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately I've never seen that syntax, but as @jvillian said you can check your `params`.

For example, if your view prints this HTML tag:

```
<input id="person_name" name="person[name]" type="text" value="Henry"/>
```

In the incoming request you will have this `params`.

```
{'person' => {'name' => 'Henry'}}
```

So the action your form points to can easily retrieve the name this way:

```
def get_value_from_form
  name = params[:person][:name]
end
```

You can find more info in the [guidelines](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/form_helpers.html#basic-structures).